# sightengine api returns fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, laravel, image, vue.js

I'm using sightengine to check image quality. I want the user to snap image with their phone and the sightengine will check the quality. If i upload an image from a folder it works fine and i get the API response, but if i try to submit an image with phone camera, it returns:

**fopen(): Filename cannot be empty**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onFileChange" capture>

 onFileChange(e){
        let form = new FormData
        form.append('file',e.target.files[0])
        axios.post('/api/drawing/checkImageQuality',form)
            .then(res=>{
            })
            .catch(e =>{
                this.isUpload = false
                this.$refs.fileInput.value = '';
                swal.fire({
                    heightAuto: false,
                    title: 'Oops',
                    text: e.response.data.message,
                    icon: 'error',
                })
            }); 
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkImageQuality(Request $request)
{
    $client = new SightengineClient(config('sightengine.user'),config('sightengine.key'));
    $output = $client->check(['properties'])->set_file($request->file);
    $sharpness = $output->sharpness;
    if($sharpness < 0.90){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image is blurry. Snap again.'], 400);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image is good.'], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" capture>`

Comment: @swadhwa I dont think it's that issue because i got the file on the controller.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($request->file);` and see if it contains what you expect it does.

Comment: yes. I got the file. The problem is: it works fine when i select a file from a pc, but if I use my phone, snap an image and try to submit, it returns the error. @RoAchterberg

Comment: can you try uploading a large file on a desktop to see if you're able to reproduce this issue

Comment: @Grey, I'm not sure I'm getting from your comment that you tried the `var_dump()` in your phone scenario. Start with the most basic assumptions and work your way up from there.